# Render entity from entity reference field

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

(Drupal 8) So I have a content type called Browse, then I have created a paragraph which is a entity reference field for content of Blog. So now when I create a piece of content in Browser I can add multiple blog posts to this page with the entity reference field from paragraphs. I can not figure out how to render the blog data into my twig template. Maybe I am using the wrong twig template file? I am trying with a field--paragraph--blog.html.twig. Does this need to be done in the theme_preprocessor?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Twig Debugging in `sites/default/services.yml`. If `services.yml` does not yet exist; copy `default.services.yml` and rename it to `services.yml`.

Set the debug variable to true:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

Now clear cache and refresh your page. Look in the html source and you should see some template suggestions.

Comment: I have that enabled but that doesn't help me figure out how to display a rendered blog from the entity reference field. I already have the twig template that I am using. And it works. But can't display the rendered blogs on this page.

Comment: Ah your content isn't being displayed yet? When you go to `Manage display`, can you change the `Format` to `Rendered entity`?

Comment: That is not an option. Just says 
Field--------Label-------Format
   Blog Reference----> Above---->Label Link to the reference entity